# Calling a future .net version assembly from .net 4 code using the dynamic keyword?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, assemblies

Will it be possible to call a future .net version (let's say .net 5) assembly from .net 4 code by using the c# dynamic keyword?

Comment: You should take the targeted framework version into account, not the programming language used to build the assembly.

Comment: Can I borrow your time machine? Sorry...but seriously. No. The assemblies would need the framework to support it.

Comment: I've edited your question as .Net 5 doesn't exist yet (you're referring to .Net 4.5 as it introduced C# 5)

Comment: @ken2k the question is indeed about future compatibility...

Answer (score 2):

No.

The dynamic keyword allows late binding of objects. The type still have to be compatible to the  .NET runtime where the program runs.

Comment: You may want to change your phrasing, dynamic is about late binding of methods or properties, not types.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: no.

If you are compiling for .net 4 in MSBUILD, the compiler will not be aware of assemblies in .net 5.

However, you should be able to target .net 5 with MSBUILD, your old code should** compile, and you will also have access to .net 5 assemblies.

As for the dynamic part - I don't believe .net 5 assemblies will be included, as the bin folder assemblies will be for the version of .net you've targeted.

[Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have no way of loading the DLL which would still be required to instantiate a variable of that type. `dynamic` just handles the complexity of runtime binding of the method to be called, it does not provide any features that weren't available before.

Could you try creating a .NET 5 COM binding that you can load between CLR boundaries.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/204406/How-To-Use-a-NET-4-Based-DLL-From-NET-2-Based-Appl

However you really should look into whether upgrading to .NET 5 or backporting the .NET 5 code to .NET 4.